# FFMPEG and MP3: equalizer filter has no effect at all

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, equalizer

Practicing FFMPEG filters on MP3s was great until I got stuck here with no luck reading from FFMPEG docs or around the web: equalizer filter has no effect at all on my MP3.

First I probed the file:

```
 libavutil      56. 49.100 / 56. 49.100
 libavcodec     58. 89.100 / 58. 89.100
 libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
 libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
 libavfilter     7. 83.100 /  7. 83.100
 libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
 libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
 libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mp3, from '.\cierre.mp3':
  Metadata:
   major_brand     : 3gp4
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: isom3gp4
   com.android.version: 10
   encoder         : Lavf58.43.100
  Duration: 00:00:14.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
```

Then I triy different combinations, understanding this would increase frequency at 1KHZ by 20 DBs, but I hear no difference inbetween source and result:

```
 .\ffmpeg -i .\cierre.mp3 -filter_complex equalizer=f=1000:g=20:c=1 -c:a libmp3lame equalized.mp3
```

Also if I ommit the (only?) channel (because as per FFPROBE it is "MONO")

```
 .\ffmpeg -i .\cierre.mp3 -filter_complex equalizer=f=1000:g=20:c=1 libmp3lame equalized.mp3
```

Is there anything to consider about the MP3? If I use VLC player's equalizer "1khz" is one of the frequencies. Other frequencies like 60HZ and 6000HZ do not show any impact either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ahah sorry, I was just no making significant changes, it was working just fine all the time, i-e- +20dB to frequency 60, too low, not noticeable - ofcourse it seems to deppend on the source properties itself.

Thanks!